Determining task length for progress bar bash
I am trying to find a way how long a progress will take so i do not hard code a set time length. I am trying to do this without adding any new libraries. the pv command seems pretty popular but my system does not support it for some reason. I am assuming there is a way SIGINFO to get this information. I tried doing a while [ ! -z pgrep command ] do \\logic to have it run while the task exists. This is for a load% for the following code:
 if [  "$selected_choice" == "Go Back" ]
  then gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat false && echo -en "\e" #This is the escape sequence in the first menu.
  else cd && cd $search_dir && jar cf $file $fileclass & bash ~/Bash_Files/Bash_Animations/load3.sh
fi

This is the code for load3.sh
#!/bin/bash

progressBarWidth=20

# Function to draw progress bar
progressBar () {

  # Calculate number of fill/empty slots in the bar
  progress=$(echo "$progressBarWidth/$taskCount*$tasksDone" | bc -l)  
  fill=$(printf "%.0f\n" $progress)
  if [ $fill -gt $progressBarWidth ]; then
    fill=$progressBarWidth
  fi
  empty=$(($fill-$progressBarWidth))

  # Percentage Calculation
  percent=$(echo "100/$taskCount*$tasksDone" | bc -l)
  percent=$(printf "%0.2f\n" $percent)
  if [ $(echo "$percent>100" | bc) -gt 0 ]; then
    percent="100.00"
  fi

  # Output to screen
  ## https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664055/how-to-print-utf-8-symbols this is why %s and %b are used
  ## ORGINAL
  ##printf "\r["
  ##printf "%${fill}s" '' | tr ' ' ▉
  ##printf "%${empty}s" '' | tr ' ' ░
  ##printf "] $percent%% - $text "
  
  #This is for GNU users as UNICODE charaters do not work on their terminal
  printf "\r["
  printf "%${fill}s" '' | sed 's/ /\o342\o226\o210/g'
  printf "%${empty}s" '' | sed 's/ /\o342\o226\o221/g'
  printf "] $percent%% - $text "
}



## Collect task count
taskCount=33
tasksDone=0

while [ $tasksDone -le $taskCount ]; do

  # Do your task
  (( tasksDone += 1 ))

  # Can add some friendly output
  # text=$(echo "somefile-$tasksDone.dat")

  # Draw the progress bar
  progressBar $taskCount $taskDone $text

  sleep 0.01
done

echo

The logic of the code works is I am just trying to dynamically assign values to taskCount and taskDone or find a different way to calculate task start to completion.

What is the question here?

how do i get the progress bar to complete when the command completes. Right now it doesnt matter what the command is it will always take the same time

There is no easy way to tell how long (or how many steps, repeats) a task will need, unless you run the task the same way every time (when you may do it once and use the info gained).
Then, to have your script actually work:
... this text:
progressBar $taskCount $taskDone $text
... needs an extra s
                     -------v
progressBar $taskCount $tasksDone $text

Then it might work... but before I discovered the above I wrote this:

function progressBar {
  all="$1"
  now="$2"
  txt="$3"
  full=48
  pcnt=$(( ( $now * 100 ) / $all  ))
  if [ $pcnt -gt 100 ] ;then pcnt=100; fi
  part=$(( $full * $pcnt / 100 ))
  rest=$(( $full - $part ))
  echo -en "\r$(
    printf "%0${part}s" | sed -re 's/ /#/g' &&  
    printf "%0${rest}s" | sed -re 's/ /./g' ) - $txt"
}

That's what i've been seeing whenever I've been looking for something like this its always hard coded. Unfortunately, it wont always be the exact same. Are you aware of any documentation on finding a task count or overall progress on something running?

Not really, you must have some kind of measure to monitor. Disk space consumed, time spent divided(?) by CPU performance (!?), a specific task appears or disappears, a signal is sent, once maybe, or 100 times (e.g. man dd - USR1).

The task that shows the Ubuntu logo at startup is Plymouth - maybe the source there has some tip on how to do it. => https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/plymouth
